# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, postgresql, type-conversion

I cannot seem to figure this out. I wrote a PHP script and I keep getting a **Array to string conversion in... Notice** as an error when trying to execute the postgres query:

```
$tables = array(array('a','table1'),array('c','table2'));
$table = $tables[0][1];
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
$select = $dbconn->prepare($query);
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($select->execute()){
}else{
    echo $select->errorInfo();
}
```

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.2.1 and the latest PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::errorInfo()` returns an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php), but you are directly echoing it, which will always result in the string `Array`.  You must store its returned array, and access the components you wish to read:

```
$err = $select->errorInfo();
print_r($err);

// Example as lifted from PHP docs linked above:
PDO::errorInfo():
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1
    [2] => near "bogus": syntax error
)
```

Incidentally, the `E_NOTICE` for array to string conversion is new in PHP 5.4.  The same code in PHP 5.3 would output `Array` as a string but would not issue the `E_NOTICE`.

Since you are using PHP 5.4, you can dereference the message `[2]` directly if you wish:

```
// 5.4+ only...
echo $select->errorInfo()[2];
```

#### Now why you are getting an error:

As to why you are entering the `else` block to report the error in the first place, you have a place holder for `:id`, but you never bound the variable `$id` before executing the query.

You may use

```
$select->execute(array(':id', $id))
```

Or

```
$select->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); // assuming an integer $id. Use PDO::PARAM_STR for strings
```